# Android- saving data that updates before restarting the application

Tags: android, save

In the Android application I'm working on, I have one activity where the user inputs data that is saved using SharedPreferences, and is used for certain calculations on the main activity. An issue I'm having is that after saving the data, the changes do not actually take effect until after the application is restarted. Is there a way I can make it so the variables associated with these SharedPreferences are updated before restarting?

Here is where I save the data in a separate activity.

```
     saveBn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            weightString = weightText.getText().toString();
            ageString = ageText.getText().toString();

            getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putString("savedWeight", weightString).commit();
            getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            .putString("savedAge", ageString).commit();

            //Intent i = new Intent("com.williammiller.capstonelapv2.MainActivity");
            //startActivity(i);

                finish();
        }
    });
```

And here is where I'm checking in the main activity to see what they are

```
    String age = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getString("savedAge", "25");

   String weight = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getString("savedWeight", "200");

    startBn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "weight = " + weightInt + " age = " + ageInt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();





        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BroadcastReceiver to achieve that. Do as following:

1. Register a BroadcastReceiver in your Main Activity:

> ```
> public static final String UPDATE_ACTION = "yourpackage.update";
> public static final String EXTRA_KEY_AGE = "key_age";
> public static final String EXTRA_KEY_WEIGHT = "key_weight";
> private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;    
>
> // In the onCreate() method
> mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
>             @Override
>           public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>                 if(intent.getAction().equals(UPDATE_ACTION)){
>                     // Here you get the update data from another activity
>                     String age = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_KEY_AGE);
>                     String weight = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_KEY_WEIGHT);
>                 }
>             }
> };
> registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(UPDATE_ACTION ));
>
> // Add the following code to onDestroy() method
> unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
> ```

2. Send a broadcast in your "separate activity":

   ```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        weightString = weightText.getText().toString();
        ageString = ageText.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.UPDATE_ACTION );
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_KEY_AGE, ageString);
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_KEY_WEIGHT, weightString );
        sendBroadcast(intent);    
     }
   ```

**Update**: Change part of the code to unregister the BroadcastReceiver when activity is destroyed.

Comment: So, I'll still need to save the data the same way, but using this it will automatically update those values. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: It's according to you. Saving the data can make them exist even the app close and open again. You don't need to save them if you only want to update them in Main Activity.